# I want facebook integration with javascript on local html file

Tags: javascript, android, html, facebook

I want facebook integration with javascript on local html file. like
`file:///Users/anil/Desktop/FB-Javascript/fb1.html`. The facebook login logout functionality works fine if I put this file on ftp. But I want to embed this fb.html file in android Webview. Now I am getting such errors.

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

How can I implement local file integration to Facebook.

Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. When you set the app up in Facebook, you must tell it the app domain where your site  will be hosted:

[image]

...and your web site address:

[image]

This can't be a `file://` on your local machine, it must be an address that Facebook can redirect or post a response to.

There is plenty of specific guidance for integrating apps on Android:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

... and mobile web clients:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/

Comment: The above mentioned suggestions works only when I pull the html file on same domain which was set up for facebook app developer page. But I need to run the html page via webview in android like mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fb1.html"); . now it does not works

Comment: Yes, as I say in my answer - what you want to do is not possible. (Or, to be precise: I don't think it is possible).

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your application on Facebook's application page. 
Configure your redirect URL to be the one used in your application